# Kineticjs Undo / Redo with event handlers, shapes and images

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs, undo-redo

I am in the middle of development of a designer drawing tool using Canvas HTML5. I will have features like: add image, add text, add shape, rotate, scale, color, etc...

I was in search of a nice way to manage action history (undo, redo) and I have found a very nice approach, you can find it here: [How to do undo redo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096875/how-to-create-undo-redo-in-kineticjs)

I was very happy that it will make my life easier than I thought, but I was wrong. It is based on `Kinetic.Node.create('json', jsonLayer);` . Though it seemed to work fine for the first sight, it has some problems:

- it looses reference to layer after remove layer and create new instead
- it looses all the image inside layer
- and the biggsest problem is that it looses event handlers inside layer, which I have many

What other possibilities could you recommend to me? I was thinking about the following:

- save the operations in an array and on undo I would do the reverse of them programatically
- serialize and store in an array each children of the layer, then on undo I would rebuild the layer (looks too complex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, a Kinetic save to JSON will not include either event handlers or images.**

You must rewire the handlers after the JSON nodes have been deserialized and rehydrated.

**With some preparation, you can even automate this rewiring.**

For example,

**First** save all your event handlers in an object or array:

```
var eventHandlers={
    myClickHandler1:function(e){ alert("Fired myClickHandler1"); },
    myClickHandler2:function(e){ alert("Fired myClickHandler2"); },
    myMouseMoveHandler1:function(e){ alert("Fired myMouseMoveHandler1"); },
    myMouseMoveHandler2:function(e){ alert("Fired mymouseMoveHandler2"); }
}
```

**Second** add a custom attribute to each Kinetic.Node that needs an event handler:

```
var circle1 = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x:100,
    y:100,
    radius: 30,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    draggable: true,
    clickEvent:"myClickHandler1"
});
```

**Finally** after the node has been rehydrated you can automatically rewire the event handlers:

```
function rewireHandlers(node){

    var handler;

    // rewire click handler
    handler=node.getAttr("clickEvent");
    if(handler && eventHandlers[handler]){
        node.on("click",eventHandlers[handler])
    }

    // rewire other event handlers the same way
}

// call for rewiring 
rewireHandlers(circle1);
```

Comment: I have some more problems maybe I will create new threads for those

Comment: This is my other problem, I donw know if you are fammiliar with it or not, I would thank you for an answer in case you are: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597030/kineticjs-undo-layers-layers-dont-disappear-on-undo