# KineticJS Undo layers: layers don't disappear on undo?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have a specific problem on my designer drawing tool in Canvas HTML5.
I am developing an action history system (Undo & Redo).
I am building my system on **projeqht**'s answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096875/how-to-create-undo-redo-in-kineticjs) with serializing the layers in history array. The core, the idea of the solution is working but I have a strange problem. When I hit Undo it creates the new layers, but the old ones are not disappearing. I will attach my sourcecode and I will attach screenshots as well so you can see what is happening:

**Sourcecode:**

```
var history = Array(null);
```

var historyStep = 0;

var arrayNonRemovable = Array('moveLayer', 'scaleFromOuterNode', 'scaleFromInnerNode', 'rotateFromOuterSign', 'rotateFromInnerSign' );

function removeLayerByUndoRedo(l)
{
    if (l)
    {
        l.destroy();
        l.draw();
        stage.draw();
    }
}

function makeHistory(layer, before, after, operation)
{
    historyStep++;
    if (historyStep

function undoHistory()
{
    if (historyStep>0)
    {
        version = history[historyStep];
        layer = version.layer;
        var beforeState = history[historyStep].before;

```
    removeLayerByUndoRedo(layer);
    var layer = Kinetic.Node.create(beforeState, 'container');
    stage.add(layer);

    stage.draw();
    historyStep--;
}
```

}

Array.prototype.contains = function(obj) {
    return this.indexOf(obj) > -1;
};

**Screenshots:**
Step 1. create the object, which contains more groups with shapes inside (lines, rectangles, SVG drawing)
[image: Creating object]
Steps 2, 3, 4, 5: Moving object to different positions (top left, bottom left, bottom right and top right):
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Step 6: Press Undo for first time (removes the old layer well and recreates it from history well):
[image]
Step 7: Press Undo for second time (creates new layer from history, but old layer is not removed)
[image]
Step 8, 9: Press Undo for another 2 times (same happens as in Step 7: creates new layer but old ones remain):
[image]

Am I doing something wrong? I think it must be something with the reference to the new layers as in Step 6 the removed layers reference is the original layer, in the following steps those are new layers, so reference should be a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what the probloem was:
I store the layer reference in the history array. So when I create an object the layer reference is stored in history[1]. I move it to 3 times, I will have the same reference in the history for all the steps. When I press undo, I am destroying the layer calling it from the stored reference and I create a new one which reference is a new one. In the history I still have the old reference, which points to NULL. This was the problem.

I have fixed it destroying the old layer calling it by name. (This only works if you give unique names to layers): `stage.find('.'+layer.getName())[0].destroy()`

Answer (score 1):

After you serialize the layer to JSON, you must do

```
yourLayer.destroy()
```

Your code seems to do this so I would need more code to find what's going wrong.

A long-shot possibility:

I see that your undoHistory references a global `layer` and also creates a local `layer`.  Try refactoring your code like this to be sure you're not mixing different "layer":

```
function undoHistory(){
   if (historyStep>0){
      var version = history[historyStep];
      var beforeState = history[historyStep].before;
      var layer1 = version.layer;
      removeLayerByUndoRedo(layer1);
      var layer2 = Kinetic.Node.create(beforeState, 'container');
      stage.add(layer2);
      stage.draw();
      historyStep--;
    }
}
```

You don't need to do l.draw() or stage.draw() after l.destroy() because the layer is being destroyed anyway and the stage is auto-updated when the layer is destroyed.

Here is a working example of layer.destroy that may help until you can post more code:

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/FSBbN/

Comment: I have tried with other variable name for layer on the new one, but the same happened.

Comment: I am describing my problem in an answer, maybe somebody will do the same mistake I did and will be useful.

Comment: Yes, I know you would need more code, the only problem is that I have too many codes that is affecting this thing so i dont know how to paste it. Fortunately your answer pointed me the right way to search the problem after. Thank you!